# Basic mysqli select

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I have a select statement where I want to get all rows from a table but seem to be having a mental blockage - this should be elementary stuff but can't seem to get it working.

There are only two rows in the table 'postage_price' - and two columns : price | ref

Select statement is as follows:

```
$get_postage="SELECT price FROM postage_price ORDER BY ref DESC";
$get_postage_result=mysqli_query($dbc, $get_postage) or die("Could not get postage");
while($post_row=mysqli_fetch_array($dbc, $get_postage_result))
{
$post1[]=$post_row;
}
```

I am then trying to echo the results out:

```
echo $post1['0'];
echo $post1['1'];
```

this is not showing anything. My headache doesn't help either.

Comment: It isn't showing anything at all or showing `ArrayArray` ?

Comment: nothing at all - all I need are to get the two values in the price column into an array and then list the values further on in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($post_row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc, $get_postage_result))
{
    $post1[] = $post_row['price'];
}
```

As you see: `$post_row` in this line: `= mysqli_fetch_array($dbc, $get_postage_result)` is an array. You are trying to save the whole array value to another array in a block. :)

**EDIT**

```
while($post_row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_postage_result))
...
```

Comment: not correct - but you have shown me my blatant error - The $dbc in the mysqli_fetch_array should not be there. I knew it was a basic error that was stopping this working :) Perhaps I started work too early this morning....

Comment: no it was my error all along - should be illegal to code on a Sunday :)

Comment: @Sideshow: Just do: `$post_row = $get_postage_result->fetch_array()` if you are tired to remember the parameters all the time (less parameters = less errors). See http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-array - it works out of the box with your code. Same for `$dbc->query($get_postage)` instead of `mysqli_query`. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

You have `$post1[]=$post_row;` and `$post_row` is itself an array. So you can access post data with following: `$post1[NUMBER][0]` where `NUMBER` is a $post1 array index and `[0]` is 0-index of $post_row returned by mysqli_fetch_array.

Probably you wanted to use `$post1[]=$post_row[0];` in your code to avoid having array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 1 and 0 as string indexes, this would only work if you had a column called 0 or 1 in you database. You need to pass them as numeric indexes.

Try:

```
print_r($post1[0]);
print_r($post1[1]);
```

or

```
print_r($post['price']);
print_r($post['ref']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If something does not work in a PHP script, first thing you can do is to gain more knowledge. You have written that

```
echo $post1['0'];
echo $post1['1'];
```

Is showing nothing. That could only be the case if those values are `NULL`, `FALSE` or an empty string.

So next step would be to either look into `$post1` first

```
var_dump($post1);
```

by dumping the variable.

The other step is that you enable error display and reporting to the highest level on top of your script so you get into the know where potential issues are:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);
```

Also you could use PHP 5.4 (the first part works with the old current PHP 5.3 as well, the `foreach` does not but you could make `query()` return something that does) and simplify your script a little, like so:

```
class MyDB extends mysqli
{
    private $throwOnError = true; # That is the die() style you do.

    public function query($query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) {
        $result = parent::query($query, $resultmode);
        if (!$result && $this->throwOnError) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Query "%s" failed: (#%d) %s', $query, $this->errno, $this->error));
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$connection = new MyDB('localhost', 'testuser', 'test', 'test');
$query      = 'SELECT `option` FROM config';
$result     = $connection->query($query);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with all your help I have found the error - it is in the mysqli_fetch_array where I had the $dbc which is not required.

```
$get_postage="SELECT price FROM postage_price ORDER BY ref DESC";
$get_postage_result=mysqli_query($dbc, $get_postage) or die("Could not get postage");
while($post_row=mysqli_fetch_array($get_postage_result))
{
$post1[]=$post_row['price'];
}
```

instead of:

```
$get_postage="SELECT price FROM postage_price ORDER BY ref DESC";
$get_postage_result=mysqli_query($dbc, $get_postage) or die("Could not get postage");
while($post_row=mysqli_fetch_array($dbc, $get_postage_result))
{
$post1[]=$post_row['price'];
}
```

Bad day for me :(

Thanks all